# Microsoft Edge - All Cookies options are disabled

Tags: microsoft-edge

I am using Microsoft Edge 25.10586.672.0 (Microsoft EdgeHTML 13.10586) on the Windows 10.
[image]

Don't know why all options of the Cookies fields are disabled, how to get it enabled to select?

Comment: Check out this documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/deploy/available-policies

Answer (score 0):

still don't know how to get the "cookies" enable but we still can config the Cookies inside the Group Policy

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/deploy/available-policies